# Android Virtual Device Manager And Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

when i am opening AVD in andorid and launching the emulator , its giving a message

`emulator window was out of view and was recentered` .

So i am not able to maximize the emulator window.

Someone please say what I can do for this.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes. Wiping the AVD config could help or a simple eclipse should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse File->Restart.
If still not solved. Check this [Link](http://android.okhelp.cz/emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentred-android-emulator-warning/).